# Projective dimension of tensor product $M\otimes M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If the projective dimension of an $R$-module $M$ is finite, then can we say that projective dimension of tensor product $M\otimes M$ (as an $R\otimes R$-module) is finite?

Comment: regarded as a module over $R\otimes R$ if $M$ is an $R$-module or do you have extra properties?

Comment: yes, regarded as a module over R⊗R  if M  is an R -module

Comment: Is it true generally? If M is projective or flat module it is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Künneth formula and depends on the ring over which you are tensoring your modules, see e.g. https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/K%C3%BCnneth_formula